# Asp.Net Core & EF 7 Inserting on Table has Trigger

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working on an ASP.NET Core app with

- Asp.Net Core
- EF 7
- .Net FrameWork 4.6

When I insert on table and this table has triggers, SQL reports the following error.

> The target table of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Why are you still using the old versions? RC1 is from December. There have  been at least one another RC version and RTM (a few weeks ago) which have changed quite a few things, maybe this one was fixed amongs other issues

Comment: There is no asp.net 5 , it's asp.net core , the next version of mvc is mvc 6